# Get The Delphi 2010 Comandline Compiler Line Number

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is there any way to get the Delphi 2010 commandline compiler (dcc32.exe) line number to pass back to a GUI application progressbar in a pipe?

As an alternative what is a good function to return the (line number) from the following strings:

```
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(20) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(339) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(341) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(512) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(1024) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(1536) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(2048) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(2560) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(3072) 
C:\Components\Dabbler\Pipes\Demos\Demo3\TestUnit\uGlobal.pas(3342)
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [JEDI JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) installer. It does exactly this, and it's open-source so you can see how it was done.

Comment: +1 Checking the JCL and/or JVCL source installer, is the way to go. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Seek to the end of the line. The character you find there should be a closing parenthesis. Seek backward to the opening parenthesis. The characters you passed over are the line number.

```
function ExtractLineNumber(const Line: string): Integer;
var
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  i := Length(Line);
  Assert(Line[i] = ')', 'unexpected line format');
  len := -1;
  while (i > 0) and (Line[i] <> '(') do begin
    Dec(i);
    Inc(len);
  end;
  Assert(i > 0, 'unexpected line format');
  Assert(len > 0, 'unexpected line format');
  Result := StrToInt(Copy(Line, i + 1, len));
end;
```

Comment: After some testing it seems like using regular expressions is the way to go to eliminate errors in ExtractLineNumber when warnings, hints and other output is generated.  Thanks to all.